# how to run multiple instances/tabs in a single chromedriver instance?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

Goal:
open chrome driver
given list of known length urls array, open each url in its own tab and click a counter.
In the urls array list the last url has functionality to go to the page and check the final count.

This is to test websockets, that's why I want to test it in a single instance.

Current solution:
Have subprocess open with a new instance each time, but this is resource intense. 
Trying to lower this resource eating by not opening another instance but rather working in the same instance.

Current solution:
Takes a medium time and most resource usage.

```
               -> open driver -> go to page -> click counter 
               -> open driver -> go to page -> click counter 
get urls[5] -> -> open driver -> go to page -> click counter 
               -> open driver -> go to page -> click counter 
               -> open driver -> go to page -> click counter
```

Wrong solution: takes longest time but least resource usage

```
open driver -> go to page -> click counter -> open tab -> go to page -> click counter -> 
....
```

Wanted Solution: (theoretically) should be a little faster if not the same as the current solution, but medium resource usage. (the usage and time cut downs happen because of one less chromedriver instance opening and all tabs processing at the same time.

```
                              -> open tab -> go to page -> click counter 
                              -> open tab -> go to page -> click counter 
open driver -> get urls[5] -> -> open tab -> go to page -> click counter 
                              -> open tab -> go to page -> click counter 
                              -> open tab -> go to page -> click counter
```

So far I have tried implementing this in golang using chromedp, which has hard to read documentation and the library is very unstable. 
The other method I have tried is python with chromedriver which is working very well but the issue is of saving as many resources as possible.

thanks a ton for any help toward the right direction!

Comment: I have no idea if this is actually possible. Have you tried copying driver object?

Comment: I have tried accessing the same chrome instance with another programmatic (python selenium scraper) instance. I haven't had any luck getting the second programmatic instance to interact with the chrome instance.